# trac_ik fails on melodic

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, trac-ik

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello list,

After loading a simple urdf in the parameter server using the following launch file:

```
<launch>
  <param name="robot_description"
    command="xacro '$(find tf_if_test)/urdf/boot.xacro' " />

  <node name="joint_state_publisher" pkg="joint_state_publisher" type="joint_state_publisher">
    <param name="use_gui" value="true"/>
  </node>

  <node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="state_publisher"/>
  <node name="rviz" pkg="rviz" type="rviz" args="-d $(find tf_if_test/launch/boot.rviz"/>
</launch>
```

This works fine, but if  I try to use `trac_ik_python`, but it fails with the following error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'ros::TimeNotInitializedException'
  what():  Cannot use ros::Time::now() before the first NodeHandle has been created or ros::start() has been called.  If this is a standalone app or test that just uses ros::Time and does not communicate over ROS, you may also call ros::Time::init()
Aborted (core dumped)
```

The code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python                                                                                                       
import rospy
from trac_ik_python.trac_ik import IK

rospy.init_node('tester', anonymous=True)
ik_solver = IK("l1",               "l3")
print 'done'
```

I thought that init_node did the ros::start() here.
Am I doing something wrong?

**EDIT:** Or is it a problem that there are only 2DOF in this robot?

**2nd EDIT:** I tried the patch by adding the ros::Timer::init() in the swig-file. That works.
Then I removed that patched version of `trac_ik` completely and reverted to the official one. Now the problem does NOT return, It is really reverted, I also rebooted the machine. Weird....

Thanks in advance, Sietse

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/312091/trac_ik-fails-on-melodic/) by [Sietse](https://answers.ros.org/users/15266/sietse/) on ROS Answers with karma: 168 on 2019-01-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I will answer my own question.

The error occurs here when the chain does NOT at least have 2 non-fixed joints in it.
I'll make a comment on the traclab issue about it.

---

Originally posted by [Sietse](https://answers.ros.org/users/15266/sietse/) with karma: 168 on 2019-01-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-01-09**:
I would have no idea how the error message you quoted would be caused by something that has to do with `fixed` or other types of joints.

**Comment by [Sietse](https://answers.ros.org/users/15266/sietse/) on 2019-01-09**:
Track_IK is not designed to be used is less than 2 (controllable) joints. It normally gives an error about that, but is doesn't do that now. My model has 2 joints, only NOT in the chain that I used for IK. So maybe the test on the number of joints is flawed.